# How can I use mongo functions in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm looking at mongodb [tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/). I want to make use of some javascript mongodb functions, but I can't see how I can do this with pymongo. I can fire up mongo shell, but this has to be done via pymongo as a part of my wsgi app.

pymongo seems to have [`Code`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/code.html#bson.code.Code) object - How can I 1)put some Code objects into my db, and 2)use them with pymongo?

Comment: which specific js mongodb functions do you mean?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky well, functions in general. if I have to be more specific, `getNextSequence` in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/ would be nice.

Comment: can't you just implement that in python? with pythons own find_and_modify insead of using evaled JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any JavaScript functions you want to run on the server have to be executed with ["eval" command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/).

You can see how to invoke that from Python [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=eval#pymongo.database.Database.eval).

You can invoke functions you have [stored on the server](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) though it's not recommended.

In general, performance of "eval" will be poor and I would recommend implementing in Python anything you were planning on implementing in JS if you are writing a Python application.  Here is a question with recent discussion of the comparison: [MongoDB performance of db.eval() in javascript shell vs. pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422243/mongodb-performance-of-db-eval-in-javascript-shell-vs-pymongo)