# calling javascript procedure with python-eve

Tags: eve

is there a way to implement some logic/coding into my GET request.

for example call an javascript procedure on the mongodb.

background is that i want to calculate average values for my stored geopoints within a given geo polygon.

best regards
Harald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook callback functions to all [database](http://python-eve.org/features#database-event-hooks) and [requests](http://python-eve.org/features#pre-request-event-hooks) events.

```
>>> def add_average(resource, response):
...     response['average values'] = my_average_values

>>> app = Eve()
>>> app.on_fetched_item += add_signature
```

From your callback you could do a PyMongo [`eval`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=eval#pymongo.database.Database.eval) to execute the JavaScript code. Keep in mind however that `eval` has been deprecated since Mongo 3.0, and is not recommended.

Quoting MongoDB's [Asya Kamsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16255503/323269):

> In general, performance of `eval` will be poor and I would recommend implementing in Python anything you were planning on implementing in JS if you are writing a Python application.

Comment: hi nicola,thanks for your reply :) i think i can solve my calculation with the new aggregation function from 0.6.3dev! nice job & cool new feature